# OS-independent intallation of scripts with setuptools

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, windows, setuptools

I am currently trying to solve an issue regarding the installation of scripts in a python project distributed with `setuptools`.
One of the scripts is

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
"""Terminal querying utility."""

from homeinfotools.query.main import main


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

located at `<projectdir>/scripts/sysquery`.
The setup script is located at `<projectdir>/setup.py` and contains the following:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
"""Installation script."""

from pathlib import Path
from setuptools import setup


setup(
    name='homeinfotools',
    version_format='{tag}',
    author='HOMEINFO - Digitale Informationssysteme GmbH',
    author_email='REDACTED',
    maintainer='Richard Neumann',
    maintainer_email='REDACTED',
    python_requires='>=3.8',
    install_requires=['setuptools-git-version', 'requests'],
    packages=[
        'homeinfotools',
        'homeinfotools.query',
        'homeinfotools.rpc',
        'homeinfotools.vpn'
    ],
    scripts=[str(path) for path in Path('scripts').iterdir()],
    license='GPLv3',
    description='HOMEINFO Digital Signage Linux configurator.'
)
```

Now I am facing the issue, that the installation via

```
python setup.py install --optimize=1
```

has a different behaviour on Windows and Linux systems.
The scripts get installed on both Windows and Linux into the corrects Paths.

- Windows: `<pythondir>\Scripts\sysquery`
- Linux: `<prefix>/bin/sysquery`

Unfortunately, I cannot invoke the scripts under Windows this way. It yields a "Command not found" error (German locales):

```
C:\Users\HOMEINFO GmbH>sysquery
Der Befehl "sysquery" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.

C:\Users\HOMEINFO GmbH>
```

The content of the script after the installation on Windows is:

```py
#!"C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe"
# EASY-INSTALL-SCRIPT: 'homeinfotools==0.0.0','sysquery'
__requires__ = 'homeinfotools==0.0.0'
__import__('pkg_resources').run_script('homeinfotools==0.0.0', 'sysquery')
```

The `PATH` is not an issue, since I can run other scripts in the same directory.
I boiled down the error to the fact, that Windows seemingly needs a `.py` suffix on the scripts in order to invoke them.
If I change the script names accordingly, I get two scripts in the `Scripts` directory:

`sysqery`

```py
#!"C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe"
# EASY-INSTALL-SCRIPT: 'homeinfotools==0.0.0','sysquery'
__requires__ = 'homeinfotools==0.0.0'
__import__('pkg_resources').run_script('homeinfotools==0.0.0', 'sysquery')
```

`sysquery.py`

```py
#!"C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe"
# EASY-INSTALL-SCRIPT: 'homeinfotools==1.0.5','sysquery.py'
__requires__ = 'homeinfotools==1.0.5'
__import__('pkg_resources').run_script('homeinfotools==1.0.5', 'sysquery.py')
```

In this case, I can run the command `sysquery` from the command line just fine.

However, this leaves the problem, that on Linux systems, the scripts then will also be installed with the `.py` suffix, which is not desired.

So I came up with an os-specific solution in `setup.py`, which works, but is ugly:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
"""Installation script."""

from os import name
from pathlib import Path
from setuptools import setup


SCRIPTS = Path('scripts').iterdir()

if name == 'nt':
    SCRIPTS = [path.rename(f'{path}.py') for path in SCRIPTS]


setup(
    name='homeinfotools',
    version_format='{tag}',
    author='HOMEINFO - Digitale Informationssysteme GmbH',
    author_email='REDACTED',
    maintainer='Richard Neumann',
    maintainer_email='REDACTED',
    python_requires='>=3.8',
    install_requires=['setuptools-git-version', 'requests'],
    packages=[
        'homeinfotools',
        'homeinfotools.query',
        'homeinfotools.rpc',
        'homeinfotools.vpn'
    ],
    scripts=[str(path) for path in SCRIPTS],
    license='GPLv3',
    description='HOMEINFO Digital Signage Linux configurator.'
)
```

**Summary**

Is it possible to install the scripts os-independent without suffixes and without having to rename them in the context of the os?

Comment: ".PY" can be added to the "PATHEXT" environment variable in Windows in order to allow shells to run `sysquery` without the extension. But running a .py script directly is unreliable. It depends on the default (usually "open") action that's associated with .py files. Ideally, .py scripts would always be associated with the py.exe launcher, which executes a script according to its shebang line, if any, else with either the version set in `PY_PYTHON` or the highest installed version. In practice, users often set the default action for .py scripts to open them in an editor or IDE.

Comment: The other problem is that opening files based on registered file associations depends on executing them via WinAPI `ShellExecuteExW`. WinAPI `CreateProcessW` can only execute PE binaries, or .BAT and .CMD batch scripts via the `ComSpec` shell. Command-line shells such as CMD will first try `CreateProcessW` and fall back on `ShellExecuteExW`. But in many contexts (e.g. Python's `subprocess.Popen`), only `CreateProcessW` is tried, in which case a .py script cannot be directly executed (i.e. opened with the default registered action).

Comment: setuptools addresses these problems in Windows by installing entrypoint scripts as launcher executables (e.g. "sysquery.exe") that include the full path to python[w].exe and an embedded small script that calls the entrypoint function. For example, the `pip` command in Windows is a "pip.exe" entrypoint script. So, your best option is to convert your scripts to use setuptools entrypoints instead of legacy scripts.